# Escape a double quote from a JSON response

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I retrieve a response from an API, and one of the data includes a double quote within it. How do I escape this double quote. When I do a JSON.parse( data ) on the data returned I get the JSONError bad object due to the double quotes in my nameinfo property.

```
"[

    {  
     "nodeid": "141478",
     "nameinfo": "My name is "my name"",
     "MODIFYDATE": "02/21/2020 02:51 PM"
    }
,

    {  
     "nodeid": "141271",
     "nameinfo": "Dior",
     "MODIFYDATE": "02/20/2020 10:20 AM"
    }
,

    {  
     "nodeid": "141270",
     "nameinfo": "Top Boy",
     "MODIFYDATE": "02/19/2020 05:56 PM"
    }
,

    {  
     "nodeid": "141265",
     "nameinfo": "[tope] - Hello Motorola",
     "MODIFYDATE": "02/19/2020 02:51 PM"
    }


]"
```

Comment: How are you retrieving the JSON? Using the Fetch API? Can you post the code?

Comment: Quotes are already *handled* in correct json. Are you dealing with *incorrect* json?

Comment: Sounds like the API needs to be fixed. It's spitting out invalid JSON. I wouldn't try to fix this on the receiving end, it's the sender that's busted.